# Artificial Neural Network Activation function can't be implemented

Tags: python, math, artificial-intelligence

My activation function right now is the logistic function f(x) = `1/(1+e^-x)`. But the values of x range from 10,000 to 100,000 so I don't think its feasible. Is there another way?

Comment: I got the data set from kaggle.com, so I think it's already normalized.

Comment: First of all, please move the question to http://cs.stackexchange.com. Secondly, I suggest you look at your data instead of just thinking about it, and providing more detail in your question. To get help, at first you need to help people understand your issue exactly.

Comment: what does this have to do with the languages tagged?

Comment: @Larssen the data isn't normalised. If it was it would range from 0 to 1, run through each feature xi and replace it with (xi-xmin)/xRange (or (xi-10000)/90000) to normalise it. Then your activation function will out values from 0 - 1